# Node on Raspberry pi running npm wiring-pi how to send bit codes?

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio, wiringpi

I'm currently trying to use node on a raspberry pi to host a HTTP server using socket.io to control it.

I currently have WASD keys binded to events ( forward, left, right, and back ) when I press the corresponding keys use light up LED's using code like this:

```
if( data.forward ) {
        console.log('forward - ON');
        wpi.digitalWrite(forwardPin, 1 );
    } else {
        console.log('forward - OFF');
        wpi.digitalWrite(forwardPin, 0 );
    }
```

This will turn off and on a LED. Now this is working, i want to now send hijack the controller of this tank i have bought.

Doing this my mimicking the signal the radio receiver sends out.

This guy has done this but in C : https://github.com/ianrenton/raspberrytank/blob/e311504642266d153ee434c85f91724a37403476/rt_ssh.c

You can see the codes in his code which are the same codes for my tank.

Here is one of them: int fwd_slow = 0xFE200F34;

I'm currently using this NPM module to control the GPIO pins (I'm totally open to other libs if you know better with better documentation).

Could someone show me a working example how to send "0xFE200F34" as a signal via a GPIO pin.?

Here is a link of his tutorial:
https://ianrenton.com/hardware/raspberry-tank/
I'm doing the same but in node only.

Comment: Nicolay, I don't have the answer, but I'm interested in seeing if I can get to it.  I'm working on making pigpio http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio easily accessible through the sockets interface via node https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-pigpio  and translating gpiozero to node - https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-gpiozero.  I'll try and find time to take a closer look at the tank C code and see if I can include the manchester encoding. I expected the real answer is with using a couple of setTimeouts.

Comment: I would really appreciate that @MikeT. Im currently stuck due to this and it's driving me a bit crazy. Im also thinking of rewriting the tank code and including either the function into node or having the file run and being able to send commands to it. Any thoughts on those options? Thanks